# Chown: filebeat.yml: operation not permitted

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I started learning how to code two months ago, so everything is very new to me. Currently I'm trying to learn how to use logstash from the elastic website (learning how to move from mysql to elasticsearch using logstash). I've got some problems and I don't know how to solve this issue:

I tried to follow the instructions from the link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

and

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/6.4/config-file-permissions.html

After I tried:

```
sudo ./filebeat -e -c filebeat.yml -d "publish"
```

I've got an error message saying:

```
"config file ("filebeat.yml") must be owned by the beat user (uid=0) or root"
```

So I tried

```
"chown 0 filebeat.yml" and "chown root filebeat.yml"
```

But it says : `"chown: filebeat.yml: Operation not permitted"`

How can I solve this problem?

I've also tried to use

```
"--strict.perms=false"
```

but it says `"-bash: --strict.perms=false: command not found"`

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo -i` enter your password root and run as it again

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ./filebeat -e --strict.perms=false
```

This starts filebeat with the flag "--strict.perms=false" set at start.